# WPF Modern Metro charts

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, charts, bar-chart

After adding below code my chart window is blank, Can you please tell me why?

Mainwindow.xaml.vb

```vb
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart

Class MainWindow
    Public Errors As New ObservableCollection(Of ChartSeries)
    Dim blocks As New ObservableCollection(Of Testclass)

    Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        barChart.Series = Errors
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim chartserie As ChartSeries = New ChartSeries
        chartserie.SeriesTitle = "India"
        chartserie.DisplayMember = "Category"
        chartserie.ValueMember = "Number"
        chartserie.ItemsSource = blocks
        Errors.Add(chartserie)
        blocks.Add(New Testclass("Global", 50))
        blocks.Add(New Testclass("Global", 50))
        blocks.Add(New Testclass("Global", 50))
        blocks.Add(New Testclass("Global", 50))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MteroChartsModern"
        xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <chart:ClusteredBarChart x:Name="barChart" ChartTitle="Population " ChartSubTitle="India ">
        </chart:ClusteredBarChart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Test class

```vb
Public Class Testclass
    Public Category As String
    Public Number As Integer

    Sub New(category As String, number As String)
        Me.Category = category
        Me.Number = number
    End Sub
End Class
```